# can't proper loop using ajax in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I always get the last value from json file, which then fades every 5 seconds. What should I do, so each value in json will appear and disappear? :(

```
   $.ajax({
         type:'GET',
         url: root + '/posts/1/comments'
           }).then(function(data){       
           $.each(data,function( i, content) {
             $('#news').html('<h3>'+ content.name + '</h3><p>' + content.name +'</p>)
                      .fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');  
               });                    
           });
});
```

Comment: Append to `$('#news')` instead of overwriting the content? https://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: but i want to overwrite it

Comment: You might want to rework this to use setTimeout() instead of delay(), it's more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you are trying to display a new piece of content in `#news` every 5 seconds. When you use `delay(5000)` it is not waiting for the last delay event to finish before firing the next one in sequence.

Instead try saving the data returned by AJAX to an array and create a function that iterates through this array. Use javascript's `setTimeout` to fire your new function every 5 seconds until it runs out of news items.

```
var news,
    newsCount,
    i;

function updateNews(){
    if (i < newsCount) {
        // add news[i] to your HTML here //
        i++;

        setTimeout(function(){
            updateNews();
        },5000);
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: root + '/posts/1/comments'
}).then(function(data) { 
    news = data;
    newsCount = news.length;
    i = 0;
    updateNews();
});
```

Comment: You might want to pass news and i to updateNews as parameters, as written updateNews does not have access to the callback's scope. Otherwise looks good.

Comment: @jeffcarey yes that is correct, thank you. I have edited and pulled the variables out to the global scope.

Comment: You need to reset "i" to 0 on the ajax response then, or else it will be where it left off last time if the ajax call is made more than once...

Comment: i'm sorry but it didn't help. i still get last value

Comment: @mrnvdvmv what data exactly is being returned from your AJAX call? Knowing what the data is and how it is marked up would be extremely helpful.

Comment: i get "vero eaque aliquid doloribus et culpa" all the time

Comment: everything is ok with this code. it was me. thank you so much

Comment: @mrnvdvmv of course! Glad I could help. If this answer worked for you, you can mark it as accepted with the checkmark under the voting arrows.